# 3 x "Syntax error on token(s)" - Basic Java declarations

Tags: java, rest

I am working on a Java RESTful Web Service, and for some strange reason I am getting 3 Java markers that I am entirely unsure of.

Here is my code:

```
package au.com.rest; //self made package
import javax.ws.rs.*; //JaxRS
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import au.edu.uts.it.wsd.*; //Package containing the relevant classes

@Path("/feedlist")
public class RESTFeedService {

String name, uri, action, feedFile;
String textReply = "Feed ";
String xmlReply = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> \n<feeds> \n";

feedFile = "/tmp/feeds.txt";
action = request.getParameter("action");
name = request.getParameter("feedName");
uri = request.getParameter("uri");

Feed feed = new Feed(name, uri);
FeedList feedList = new FeedListImpl();

feedList.load(feedFile);

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String showTextFeeds()
{
    for (Feed f:feedList.list()){
        textReply += "[Feed Name: " + f.getName() + ", ";
        textReply += "[Feed URI: " + f.getURI() + "]"; }
    return textReply;
}
```

The errors I am getting are on the following lines:

```
String xmlReply = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> \n<feeds> \n";
```

**Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token**

```
feedFile = "/tmp/feeds.txt";
```

**Syntax error on token "String", @ expected**

```
public String showTextFeeds()
```

**Syntax error on token(s), misplaced constructs**

Please point me in the right direction as to what it is I am doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: Note: this following section of code compiles just fine?
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public String showXmlFeeds()
 {
  for (Feed f:feedList.list()){
   xmlReply += "    <feed> \n        <name>" + f.getName() + "</name> \n";
   xmlReply += "        <uri>" + f.getURI() + "</uri> \n    </feed> \n</feeds>";
  }
  return xmlReply;
 }

Comment: The above code is exactly the same as the "showTextFeeds" method in the original post, although it returns XML instead of plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String name, uri, action, feedFile;

feedFile = "/tmp/feeds.txt";
action = request.getParameter("action");
name = request.getParameter("feedName");
uri = request.getParameter("uri");
```

should be

```
String name = request.getParameter("feedName");
String uri = request.getParameter("uri");
String feedFile  = "/tmp/feeds.txt";
String action = request.getParameter("action");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have code where you can only have fields.  You can move these to a constructor.

```
public RESTFeedService(Request request) {
    feedFile = "/tmp/feeds.txt";
    action = request.getParameter("action");
    name = request.getParameter("feedName");
    uri = request.getParameter("uri");

    feed = new Feed(name, uri);
    feedList = new FeedListImpl();

    feedList.load(feedFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put arbitrary statements at class level. Statements like assignments and `feedList.load(feedFile);` must be in a method, not at class level, outside a method.